# How to have marquee effect on IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Following is the marquee that works on chrome and firefox. But it doesn't work for `Internet Explorer`. Why is that ? How can I make it work ? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQS4U/) for it.

*HTML*

```
<p class="marquee">
    <span>
        Hey! What's up? <br />
        Second Line <br />
        Third Line <br />
        Fourth Line <br />
        Fifth Line <br /    
    </span>
```

*CSS*

```
    /* define the animation */
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%); }
} 
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(0, -100%); }
} 


/* define your limiting container */
.marquee {
  border: solid 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: #0aa2e3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:60px;
}
/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
  -webkit-animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}
/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: In your CSS, you have vendor-prefixed keyframe animations for Webkit and Mozilla, but you haven't defined anything for IE (or the non-prefixed animation property) so it has no animation to run.

Comment: (Comment on post formatting: you can add `<!-- language: lang-css -->` and an empty line before and after it. This will highlight the code properly.)

Answer (score 2):

you only added the `keyframe vendor prefix` for `MOZILLA` and `WEBKIT` but haven't use the standard one `@keyframes`.

HAve a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hiqijuha/1/edit)**.

```
    /* Standard animation */
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(0, -100%); }
}
```

Comment: Is it the only necessity for IE ?

Comment: I mean do I need to add only this statement ?

Comment: Well, all latest browsers support it. however if you are worries for older versions of Mozilla and chrome you could add vendor prefix.

Comment: @saplingPro This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using? CSS3 animation isn't supported below IE10 (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

EDIT: Ah yeah, there's also the problem of not using the standardised markup as highlighted by Kheema.

Answer (score 0):

Make marquee element fixed width with *overflow:hidden*, and the inner span width enough to fit in horizontal all elements, then with plain JS change the *marginLeft* to negative.

```
m = document.getElementsByClassName('marquee')[0];
mw = m.offsetWidth * -1;
mL = 0;
setInterval(marquee, 15);
function marquee() {
  mL -= 1;
  if (mL <= mw) mL = 0;
  m.getElementsByTagName('pan')[0].style.marginLeft = mL + "px";
}
```